# Java stream, how to apply a function to the previous result

Tags: java

I was looking for a right answer, but found nothing that fill my purpose.

I have a simple for loop like this:

```
String test = "hi";
    
for(Something something : somethingList) {
    if(something.getSomething() != null) {
        test = cleaner.clean(test, something.getSomething());
    } else if(something.getOther() != null) {
        test = StaticClass.clean(test, something.getOther());
    }
}
```

and I never understood if the same result can be achieved using java stream. With reduce maybe? I need to pass the response of the previuos loop (saved in the "test" variable) to the next loop (see clean method, where I pass test). How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, `reduce()` would be an option, e.g.soemthing like `reduce("hi", (test, something) -> { String newTest = /*your code*/; return newTest; })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, with streams you basically could use reduction, e.g. by using the `reduce()` method.

Example:

```
//some list simulating your somethingList
List<Integer> list = List.of(2,4,6,1,3,5);

String result = list.stream()
        //make sure the stream is sequential to keep processing order
        .sequential() 
        //start reduction with an initial value
        .reduce("initial", 
            //in the accumulator you get the previous reduction result and the current element
            (test, element) -> {
                //simulates your conditions, just adding the new element for demonstration purposes
                // test could also be replaced
                if( element % 2 == 0 ) {                    
                    test += ", even:" + element;
                } else {
                    test += ", odd: " + element;
                }
                //return the new reduction result
                return test;
            }, 
            //combiner is not used in sequential streams so just one of the elements
            (l, r) -> l);
```

This would result in:

```
initial, even:2, even:4, even:6, odd: 1, odd: 3, odd: 5
```

Note, however, that streams are not a silver bullet and sometimes a simple loop like your initial code is just fine or even better. This seems to be such a case.

Comment: I agree with your last statement, but even for this case, the use of the stream API might be a good choice. You don't have to worry about how to efficiently loop over your list and using streams you get all the benefits that are coming with them, for example processing in parallel or an infinite amount of data or remapping your whole data altogether to a new container. All these operations can become basically a one-liner.

Comment: @Sebphil you're basically right but in the OP's case you'd not want to use parallel processing since that would seem to break the logic. If you already have a list or collection then using a loop would be at least as efficient as using a stream. Of course if you need more advanced features like mapping, filtering, advanced collecting etc. streams would come in handy but they also make it hard to debug such a process or even to develop it. So they should be used consciously - just as everything else should be used. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something for each element in a list (with a for each loop) I would suggest using the [`forEach` or `forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) functions. These should represent your `for(Object o : objects)`. You can easily define your own [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) class, which handles all the stuff for you:

```java
class CustomConsumer implements Consumer<Integer> {

        private Integer previous;

        public CustomConsumer(Integer initialValue) {
            previous = initialValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(Integer current) {
            // do stuff with your current / previous object :)
            System.out.println("previous: " + previous);
            previous = current;
        }
}

List<Integer> values = getValues();

values.stream()
        .forEachOrdered(new CustomConsumer(-1));
```

This example uses Integer as a provided class, if you want to use your own just replace `Integer`. You can even use generics:

```java
class CustomConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {

        private T previous;

        public CustomConsumer(T initialValue) {
            previous = initialValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(T current) {
            // do stuff with your current / previous object :)
            System.out.println("previous: " + previous);
            previous = current;
    }
}

List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    values.add(i);

values.stream()
        .forEachOrdered(new CustomConsumer<>("hello"));
```

Output:

```
previous: hello
previous: 0
previous: 1
previous: 2
previous: 3
previous: 4
```

If you want to learn more about streams the oracle docs provide some [good stuff](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).